# Sparse Tensor (matrix) from a dense Tensor Tensorflow

Tags: python, graph, tensorflow, sparse-matrix, autoencoder

I am creating a convolutional sparse autoencoder and I need to convert a 4D matrix full of values (whose shape is `[samples, N, N, D]`) into a sparse matrix.

For each sample, I have D NxN feature maps. I want to convert each NxN feature map to a sparse matrix, with the maximum value mapped to 1 and all the others to 0.

I do not want to do this at run time but during the Graph declaration (because I need to use the resulting sparse matrix as an input to other graph operations), but I do not understand how to get the indices to build the sparse matrix.

Comment: Do you want to do this conversion in Tensorflow or in python? If in python This function can help you convert from dense to sparse matrix (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix) And you can use tf.SparseTensor (which uses coo format) to store each feature map, and use a list to store all sparse tensors.

Comment: Specifically, nonzero() (http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.nonzero.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.nonzero) can give you the indices for nonzero elements. Not sure if this is considered the runtime approach. This could be some data preprocessing before the graph declaration. Is the 4D dense matrix generated at runtime or simply some given input data?

Comment: I don't want to do that at runtime (I know how to do that with numpy) but during the graph declaration (so with Tensorflow)

Answer (score 17):

You can use `tf.where` and `tf.gather_nd` to do that:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

# Make a tensor from a constant
a = np.reshape(np.arange(24), (3, 4, 2))
a_t = tf.constant(a)
# Find indices where the tensor is not zero
idx = tf.where(tf.not_equal(a_t, 0))
# Make the sparse tensor
# Use tf.shape(a_t, out_type=tf.int64) instead of a_t.get_shape()
# if tensor shape is dynamic
sparse = tf.SparseTensor(idx, tf.gather_nd(a_t, idx), a_t.get_shape())
# Make a dense tensor back from the sparse one, only to check result is correct
dense = tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(sparse)
# Check result
with tf.Session() as sess:
    b = sess.run(dense)
np.all(a == b)
>>> True
```

Comment: How do I do this with tensors? Like I want to convert a tensor into a sparse one.

Comment: @RocketPingu Not sure what you mean, this is to convert a dense tensor into a sparse one. `a_t` here is a regular TensorFlow tensor (in this case is obtained from the `tf.constant` op but could be the output of any other op). I've added some comments for clarity.

Comment: It's just when I tried it for my code, it gave me an error. More on it over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48201725/converting-tensor-to-a-sparsetensor

Comment: @RocketPingu As I put in one of the comments in the code, if the full shape of the tensor is not known at the time of graph creation (i.e. its shape is dynamic, not static), you should use `tf.shape(tensor)` instead of `tensor.get_shape()` or `tensor.shape`.

Comment: I run the code again. It turns out the conversion is successful. The issue now lies in the ctc_loss. Thanks!

Comment: I do have a question. In `idx = tf.where(tf.not_equal(a_t, 0))`, why do we look for indices that are not equal to 0? Can it be an arbitrary number?

Comment: @RocketPingu No, as you can see [in the documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor) a sparse tensor is defined through its nonzero values (in TensorFlow, but also in about any algebra package that defines sparse structures). A matrix or tensor is said to be sparse if most of its elements are zero, and so this representation is much more economical (although operating with it is generally more complex).

Answer (score 3):

Simple code to convert dense numpy array to tf.SparseTensor:

```
def denseNDArrayToSparseTensor(arr):
  idx  = np.where(arr != 0.0)
  return tf.SparseTensor(np.vstack(idx).T, arr[idx], arr.shape)
```

Answer (score 1):

Tensorflow has [`tf.sparse.from_dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/from_dense) since 1.15. Example:

```
In [1]: import tensorflow as tf

In [2]: x = tf.eye(3) * 5

In [3]: x
Out[3]: 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[5., 0., 0.],
       [0., 5., 0.],
       [0., 0., 5.]], dtype=float32)>
```

Applying `tf.sparse.from_dense`:

```
In [4]: y = tf.sparse.from_dense(x)

In [5]: y.values
Out[5]: <tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([5., 5., 5.], dtype=float32)>

In [6]: y.indices
Out[6]: 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2), dtype=int64, numpy=
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [2, 2]])>
```

Verify identity by applying [`tf.sparse.to_dense`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/sparse/to_dense):

```
In [7]: tf.sparse.to_dense(y) == x
Out[7]: 
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=bool, numpy=
array([[ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True]])>
```

Comment: If one is interested in the current impl: [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/9a7c57d1d810b32679ad31dbce7ffea94e3be896/tensorflow/python/ops/sparse_ops.py#L107-L136)

Answer (score 0):

Note there is a built in function in the [contrib](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/layers/dense_to_sparse) (taken [from](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51484756/2964927) )

Answer (score 0):

In TF 2.3 [Tensorflow Probability](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability) has a [function](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/math/dense_to_sparse) for this:

```
import tensorflow_probability as tfp

tfp.math.dense_to_sparse(x, ignore_value=None, name=None)
```