# tf.SparseTensor and tf.nn.ctc_loss

Tags: tensorflow

I would like to restructure my labels for the first argument in `tf.nn.ctc_loss`.

The labels are stored in a Tensor `labels` of `shape=[batch_size x max_time]`, and since the second dimension has been padded with zeros, the true lengths of the labels are stored in another Tensor `labels_length` of `shape=[batch_size]`.

It is unclear to me what the `labels` argument of `tf.nn.ctc_loss` should look like. I am reading that it should be a `SparseTensor`. What is the correct shape and contents of `indices`, `values` and `dense_shape` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, your current input `labels` looks like this:

```
[[4, 3, 1, 2, 5],
 [2, 3, 4, 1, 0],
 [1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
 [5, 4, 0, 0, 0]]
```

in which we have `batch_size=4`, `max_time=5`, and `labels_length=[5,4,3,2]`.

If that is the case, you can convert it to `SparseTensor` with the same approach described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39838234/sparse-matrix-from-a-dense-one-tensorflow). Thus there is no need to use `labeles_length` as long as you always pad with zeros.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
labels = tf.Variable([[4, 3, 1, 2, 5],
                      [2, 3, 4, 1, 0],
                      [1, 2, 3, 0, 0],
                      [5, 4, 0, 0, 0]], tf.int32)
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  idx = tf.where(tf.not_equal(labels, 0))
  sparse = tf.SparseTensor(idx, tf.gather_nd(labels, idx), labels.get_shape())
  s = sess.run(sparse)
  print s.indices
  print s.values
  print s.dense_shape

> [[0 0]
   [0 1]
   [0 2]
   [0 3]
   [0 4]
   [1 0]
   [1 1]
   [1 2]
   [1 3]
   [2 0]
   [2 1]
   [2 2]
   [3 0]
   [3 1]]
> [4 3 1 2 5 2 3 4 1 1 2 3 5 4]
> [4 5]
```

To better understand sparse tensor (actually it is not a tensor but a wrapper around three tensors), see the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/SparseTensor).

Comment: Could you please update your answer for the particular case when the shape of the labels Tensor cannot be inferred while building the graph ? e.g. `shape=[?,?]`, this will currently throw: `ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (?, ?)`

Comment: Also, your solution is much more elegant than in [ctc_labels_dense_to_sparse](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.3/tensorflow/contrib/keras/python/keras/backend.py#L3836) from Keras that I have found after posting here, only one line to compute the indices. The results in my case look identical with the two solutions.

Comment: Use `tf.shape(labels, out_type=tf.int32) instead of labels.get_shape()` if tensor shape is dynamic. Or there is a more general snippet for `get_shape`[here](https://github.com/vahidk/EffectiveTensorflow#get-shape-).